# How to open manage-account page within iframe in keycloak

Tags: iframe, keycloak

- I am trying to open keycloak `manage-account` page using iframe into my application, but I'm getting an error.

---

**Browser log**
[image]

**Below is keycloak configuration**

[image]

***NOTE: Working in firefox, but not in Chrome***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome, it is not working due to the `SameSite` setting in the chrome browser. To enable the working for the above problem you just need to follow the below steps and your problem gets resolved.

- Go to chrome://flags/
- Search for `Samesite`
- Disable "SameSite by default cookies" flags.
- Relaunch